# Making a decision using array of the character type

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement

So what I'm trying to do is to get a result by reading if certain characters are contained within the arrays. First the Strings are converted to arrays of the character type so that each letter becomes a value and not just the whole word becoming one value. then the if statement should check if the arrays contain the specified letters and give the result.

```
public class string {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println  ("  hello world");

        String name = "y";
        String surname = "o";

        long id = 45;

        char[] cname = new char[name.length()];

        char[] csurname = new char[surname.length()];



        if (cname.contains("q") && csurname.contains("d")) {
            System.out.println("aa" + id + "zz");

        }else{
            System.out.println("gg" + id + "gg");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that `"q" + "p" + " a" + "z"` turns this into the String `"qpaz"`, right? You probably want to do separate boolean tests for each letter, no? Or use Regex.

Comment: BTW `new String(cname)` is creating a string full of `\u0000` since the arrays are full of that character (initial value)

Comment: Every time you edit the question, it invalidates the comments you've been given so far.

Answer (score 1):

`new char[name.length()];` creates an array of that length, all with `\u0000` (null character). You would need to initialize all positions to the needed values like `cname[0] = 'y'`;

---

You shouldn't need to do that since to get an array from a String, you'd use `.toCharArray()`.

However, arrays do not have `.contains` method, only lists do...

---

To test if a substring is in another string, you don't need arrays, just call `.contains()` *on the string*.

```
String name = "y";
String surname = "o";
int id = 45;
if (name.contains("q") && surname.contains("d")) {
    System.out.printf("aa%dzz%n", id);
} else {
    System.out.printf("gg%dgg%n", id);
}
```